# Blazor Material Design Component library

Tags: asp.net-core, nuget, material-design, blazor

In this presentation Steve Sanderson demos many cool features of Blazor.

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=0RfUPr0KrSM

He mentions MDC at a glance but doesnt dive too deep into it. I am wondering if anybody knows if the MDC components he used (like MdcList) is his custom component or if he got that from a library?

I downloaded the MatBlazor Nuget, and I'm unable to display a simple progress bar. So I'm not having any luck with this.

Comment: I've added an answer to your direct question. However, would suggest you either raise an issue on the MatBlazor GitHub. Or rework this question to ask for help on how you've implemented the progress bar control.

Comment: I agree with Chris, you can however use MatBlazor for Blazor applications to get Material Design Components: https://www.matblazor.com/

Comment: There is also Skclusive-UI, a quite good looking Material Design component library for Blazor: https://skclusive.github.io/Skclusive.Material.Docs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the MDC components Steve uses in this presentation he built himself.